# Jgit RevWalk.parseCommit() throw MissingObjectException

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have a repository with some test commit (all on default branch).
Using JGit log command, I can see these commit ( for exemple):

```
RepositoryBuilder builder = new RepositoryBuilder();
Repository repository = builder.setWorkTree("/tmp/myworkingdir").readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
Git git = new Git(repository);

for (RevCommit commit : git.log().call()) {
    System.out.println("commit: " + commit.getId());
}
```

Result:

```
commit: commit f34a848371ff334b2e85aa16fbf9b871d028b443 1371652639 ----sp
commit: commit 33603f8c1c47712d45eb0db4b1827bbd113c2428 1371652639 ----sp
commit: commit d52bd5c768263a957d99975f5482020ffc3434d5 1371652639 ----sp
```

But when I try to get a RevCommit from the String SHA1 it fails on the last line of this snippet:

```
ObjectId revid = repository.resolve("33603f8c1c47712d45eb0db4b1827bbd113c2428");
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(revid);
```

Exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 33603f8c1c47712d45eb0db4b1827bbd113c2428
at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:817)
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:730)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Solution**
Init of the Repository was wrong on the access part..

Comment: Your use of the API seems correct. Are you sure that `repository` and `git.getRepository()` are the same repository? How do you run this code, is the repository you are working on generated by earlier code (in which case the commit IDs would differ because of commit time)?

Comment: I tried both repository and git.getRepository(), no change.
The repository is generated by earlier code yes, but in my real case scenario the commit ID is fetched from the git log command each time, and it's not supposed to change between generation and access.. :s

Comment: I've also tried with a repository directly cloned from github and I get the same issue..
I use git log, take one commit id "randomly", and try to access it after, and it results in this org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException...

Comment: Please post the full source code then, so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: Okay my mistake.. Init of the Repository was wrong for the afterwards access (a sub directory instead of the root). But I would have expected another error.. :s Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post your last comment as an answer and accept it, so that this question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my mistake.. 
Init of the Repository was wrong for the afterwards access (a sub directory instead of the root). 
But I would have expected another error..

Here a snippet showing the issue:

```
    String wpath = "/tmp/test-git";
    ArrayList<String> commits = new ArrayList<String>();

    // get list of commit
    {
        File gitDir = new File(wpath);
        RepositoryBuilder builder = new RepositoryBuilder();
        Repository repository = builder.setWorkTree(gitDir)
                .readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
        Git git = new Git(repository);

        for (RevCommit commit : git.log().call()) {
            String cid = commit.getId().toString().split(" ")[1];
            commits.add(cid);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(commits);
    }

    // Random access
    {
        File gitDir = new File(wpath + "/subdir");
        RepositoryBuilder builder = new RepositoryBuilder();
        Repository repository = builder.setWorkTree(gitDir)
                .readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();

        for (String cid : commits) {
            RevCommit commit = CommitUtils.getCommit(repository, cid);
            assertEquals(commit.getId().toString().split(" ")[1], cid);
        }
    }
```

It shouldn't work since the repository is wrongly initialized (on the second part), but the error should tell it.. :/